# how to use knockoutjs and its available plugins with requirejs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, knockout-mapping-plugin

Hi my question is specific to libraries/plugins that depend on knockout.

Currently, I'm implementing `requirejs` in my existing project, a multi-page app.

This is what I currently have,

my **common.js**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/Scripts/',
    paths: {
        ko: '/Scripts/lib/knockout-3.3.0',
        jquery: '/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2',
        domReady: '/Scripts/lib/domReady'
    }
});
```

**file1.js**

```
define(['ko', 'jquery'], function(ko, $){
  // code goes here
});
```

Above worked perfectly, until I need to use the `knockoutjs-mapping` (that I downloaded via nuget) plugin for knockout.

How will I include the `knockoutjs-mapping` in my project and make sure `knockoutjs` was loaded first before this or any 3rd party library. And how can I use it?

I tried something like this:

```
define(['ko', 'jquery', 'mapping'], function(ko, $, mapping) {
});
```

But not working,

And I saw this [link](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map) but can't seem to figure out how to implement it. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: On a general note, you might want to look into https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-amd-helpers

Comment: I tried the one that was suggested as duplicated question, the answer with most votes did not worked

Comment: "Not working" is not an error description. Can you be a little bit more specific?

Comment: `define(['ko', 'jquery', 'mapping'], function(ko, $, mapping) {
});` I did it like this but I said knockoutjs cannot be found and Im sure I included ko correctly in my config

Comment: Read http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/amd-loading.html. I suspect that your knockout file is not really called `ko.js`.